# getElementById me funciona alternativamente

Tags: dom

Tengo una lista y una función que elimina el primer elemento cuando se la llama.
El problema se presenta porque solo funciona en las pulsaciones pares. Debo pulsar el botón dos veces para que elimine una entrada de la cabecera de la lista.
Paso un ejemplo:

```
   <script>
        function elimina()
        {
            //elimina el primer hijo
            var parent = document.getElementById("lista");
            var child = parent.firstChild;
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }
    </script>


<body>
    <ul id="lista">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Sed mattis enim vitae orci</li>
        <li>Phasellus libero</li>
        <li>Maecenas nisl arcu</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar elemento" onclick="elimina();">
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando la propiedad firstChild que obtiene el valor de la lista de nodos del dom, donde no solo aplican los elementos HTML sino tmb texto, espacios en blanco, comentarios etc.

Como tu html tiene saltos de lineas, si te fijas en los nodes, incluye esos saltos. Lo que debes hacer es solamente usar el HtmlCollection, donde se listan solo los elementos de html.

```js
    function elimina()
        {
            //elimina el primer hijo
            var parent = document.getElementById("lista");
            var child = parent.children[0];
            if (child) {
              parent.removeChild(child);
            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <ul id="lista">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Sed mattis enim vitae orci</li>
        <li>Phasellus libero</li>
        <li>Maecenas nisl arcu</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar elemento" onclick="elimina();">
    
</body>
```

Comment: Cierto: Los espacios en blanco dentro de los elementos se consideran como texto, y el texto se considera como nodos y los comentarios también. Gracias, a veces se te olvida hasta sumar con los dedos.